# Можно ли достать из фала .obj данные о каждом объекте, координаты, хоть что-нибудь?

Tags: three.js, webgl, obj

Есть модель, подобие мини карты, одна сделана в одном фале obj, а затем материалы mtl сверху налаживаются. Задача:как мы можем на этой карте кликнуть, например, на домик, чтобы привязать событие.
Для обработки этих файлов использую mtlLoader и objLoader

скрин карты - http://joxi.ru/RmzVx04He3yRmO

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то по клику на объекте нужно узнать что он есть такое. Тогда для этой цели подойдет использование [THREE.Raycaster()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=raycaster#Reference/Core/Raycaster). В вашем случае для нахождения всех объектов в сцене, пересекаемых лучом `raycaster`'а, вторым параметром метода `.intersectObjects()` необходимо указать `true`:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );
```

Если массив пересеченных объектов не пустой, то первый же объект в нем (ближайший к наблюдателю вдоль луча) - и есть тот, информацию о котором нужно получить:

```
var theObjectYouNeed = intersects[0].object;
console.log( theObjectYouNeed );
```

Comment: а если модель сделана будет в одном файле obj, луч увидит только один объект?

Comment: Если obj-файл будет содержать один супер-объект - это будет более чем странно. Так обычно не делают. Obj-файл содержит объекты (с вершинами, треугольниками, uv-координатами и т.д, и т.п.), которые в свою очередь могут быть объединены в группы. Описание формата Wavefront .obj можно почитать [здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) или [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obj). Английская версия лучше, так как расписана более подробно.